# Detect Chrome switch allow-running-insecure-content from a webpage

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, security

I have a SSO login page built in ASP.NET where I authenticate users and then pass them onto another system. This other system, for unknown reasons, requires that Chrome be running with the switch --allow-running-insecure-content in order for some external peripheral devices to run with their website.

My customer is wanting to ensure the current Chrome browser instance is running with this flag/switch set, and if not to display an error/warning message.

Is there any way of detecting this within Chrome itself from ASP.NET? Or, perhaps a way to simulate loading a resource that requires the switch to be set, and then detecting if that resource loaded or not?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way from the *client-side* to detect whether Chrome is running with `--allow-running-insecure-content`.

The trick is to add an insecure resource to the web page and then check to see if that resource was loaded using JavaScript. Using its normal security parameters, Chrome will not load insecure resources from a secure context.

Here's some sample code that does this:

**HTML:**

```
<!-- When Chrome is run in insecure mode, as desired, this message will be removed -->
<div class="not-insecure-warning">
  Your browser is not configured properly. You must access this page with Chrome using <code>--allow-running-insecure-content</code>. <a href="#">Learn more.</a>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
// Remove `.not-insecure-warning` elements
function removeNotInsecureWarning(){
  var warnings = document.getElementsByClassName('not-insecure-warning');
  for(var i = 0; i < warnings.length; i++){
    var warning = warnings[i];
    warning.parentNode.removeChild(warning);
  }
}

var insecureScript = document.createElement('script');
// TODO: Replace URL to an empty `.js` file served over HTTP
insecureScript.src = 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js';
// If this insecure script loads, then the browser is running in insecure mode, remove the warning
insecureScript.addEventListener('load', removeNotInsecureWarning);
document.body.append(insecureScript);
```

[**See this example on JSFiddle.**](https://jsfiddle.net/nwvr0j9y/7/) You should see the warning if you're running Chrome normally, but if you open a new window with insecure content allowed, the warning on this page will disappear.

If you need to pass this information to your server-side logic, you can either:

1. Use AJAX. Send an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) if the insecure script fails to load using an event listener like `insecureScript.addEventListener('error', isSecureSendPOSTRequest);`
2. Use a hidden form input `<input name="is_insecure" type="hidden" value="0">` that you can process immediately after the user logs-in. You can toggle the `value` of this input using the same kind of client-side logic shown above.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know about a direct solution , but a possible solution is that you can open chrome using the shell script in the c# as follows.

```
class Module1 {

    static void Main() {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("chrome.exe", "--allow-running-insecure-content");
         }
      }
```

As you want to add `--allow-running-insecure-content` for loading the browser with that flag

Comment: I believe OP is trying to know the details in the browser context...Possibly using Javascript.

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan neither in question nor in tag , i didnt find using javascript. and he want to access the application in browser using that flag, so we can launch the browser with that flag and open the application.. its just a way to represent

Comment: Still, I dont believe an `ASP.NET` page would be able to do a `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()` on a client machine.. This has a potential of remotely running literally anything on the client machine, say `rm -rf`

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan have you tried?  we can invoke powershell scripts from c# and from there you can able to trigger chrome browser

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan you didn't answer my basic question which i answered in my initial comments 1. you need in Javascript? 2. are you trying to specifically asking to trigger using the chrome browser on client user machine? 3. Elaborate the Orginal Question , simply Adding a Bounty doesnt get a rightful solution .  i'm not offending your opinon but it would be nice if you can elaborate the question more . sorry if i'm being rude

Comment: Yes, I would like to see if this can be done in javascript. And the OP's words may be misleading. But he does mention `within Chrome itself from ASP.NET`

Comment: @RajaAnbazhagan `within Chrome itself from ASP.NET` doesn't tell that it needs to execute in Javascript right. and did you read this out `current Chrome browser instance is running with this flag/switch set` from OP words ?

Comment: So how do you detect it if the chrome is not running with that flag...? that's the question. Or probably how to set this flag within chrome itself instead of starting a new browser instance